# How do I keep the SVG overlays fixed on the image inside the container?

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to make the background image and SVG responsive. I have got them both in a container,where both are responsive from their own perspectives. But When I test it by Stretching the browser in and out,the SVG gets displaced. I need to fix the SVG overlays over the background image,where they will be settled at the position of the image I have set them.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        .container {
            background: url(http://i.imgur.com/b1K76Pf.jpg) no-repeat;
            background-size: contain;
            max-width: 960px;
            height: 565px;
            margin: auto;
        }
        
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="main-roof">
            <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewbox="0 0 1200 180" 
preserveAspectRatio="none">

<polygon fill="red" points="115,103 643,93 930,47 372,72">
</polygon> 
<polygon fill="red" points="30,120 170,112 649,105 513,118 ">
</polygon>
<polygon fill="red" points="610,49 642,57 600,56 576,57">
</polygon> 
            </svg>
         </div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

P.S. I have tried the `.container` with width and height of `%` and `auto`,but in that case,the image just doesn't show up.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your described behavior. I made a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aL7keb3u/. I ran it in FF54 and Chrome59. In both browsers the SVG resized the same as the bg-image in the container.

Comment: Have you tried resizing it manually? By stretching the browser in and out?

Comment: Yes, of course. That's why I wrote that both resized the same. _(To only open the result of my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aL7keb3u/embedded/result/)_

Comment: Yes they do.
The problem is,they resize accordingly but gets misplaced from the place I draw them in different screen sizes. I have more 3 webpages with same concept,but they seem to resize as I want,but not only this one.

This is one of the example which is working - https://pastebin.com/aj2As42f

And this is how the one I am having problem with should look like in every screen sizes. - http://i.imgur.com/qtxYuMm.png

Updated code on the first one - https://pastebin.com/AWzdRune

Comment: So like this: https://jsfiddle.net/aL7keb3u/2/? (I just set the same height as the container on the SVG.) --- It seems your SVG is misformatted, because as I can see in your `viewbox` the SVGs resolution is 1280x180px which is pretty wide and flat and results in the exact "stretched" look. _(BTW. I don't have a pastebin account, and I cannot load your bg.jpg or scripts.js. So I only see the color palette and the three links - and nothing happens on clicking on a color or link.)_

Comment: FYI:  Also `mix-blend-mode: multiply;` could have a nice effect _(at least in FF and Webkit-Browsers: http://caniuse.com/#search=mix-blend-mode)_ as you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/aL7keb3u/3/

Comment: I think I finally understood what you're trying to accomplish here. You want a SVG which scales according to the browser window, but in the same aspect ratio as the (background) image. Without having to set absolute pixel values, but relative ones. Right? If so, may that be helpfull to you: https://jsfiddle.net/aL7keb3u/4/?

Comment: I also noticed the viewbox difference between them, but when I tried by changing it, it wasn't working aswell. Guess where the problem actually was? I typed `</DOCTYPE html>` instead of `<!DOCTYPE html>` and that's why none of the solutions were working as they should've. Still laughing at those hours I struggled with it lol.
Changing the viewbox and setting up the coords worked like it should've. I also saw your fiddle which helped me to know certain things. Thanks for the help though, appreciated. ^_^ @Seika85

Answer (score 1):

*So to close this question I summon up our comments as an answer.*

I cannot reproduce your described behavior. I made a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aL7keb3u. I ran it in FF54 and Chrome59. In both browsers the SVG resized the same as the bg-image in the container.

You want a SVG which scales according to the browser window, but in the same aspect ratio as the (background) image. Without having to set absolute pixel values, but relative ones. Right? If so, may that be helpfull to you: https://jsfiddle.net/aL7keb3u/4?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/b1K76Pf.jpg" class="bg_image" />
  <div class="main-roof">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewbox="0 0 1200 180" 
         preserveAspectRatio="none">

      <polygon fill="red" points="115,103 643,93 930,47 372,72">
      </polygon>    
      <polygon fill="red" points="30,120 170,112 649,105 513,118 ">
      </polygon>
      <polygon fill="red" points="610,49 642,57 600,56 576,57">
      </polygon>    
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
  /*background: url(http://i.imgur.com/b1K76Pf.jpg) no-repeat;*/
  /*background-size: contain;*/
  max-width: 960px;
  /*height: 565px;*/
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

/* ---------------------- */

.container > img.bg_image {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.main-roof {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;

    mix-blend-mode: multiply; /* nice effect */

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
svg {
    /*height: 565px;*/
    width: 100%;
    height: 103.5%;
}
```

As you yourself stated the issue was due to invalid HTML. Please validate your HTML first, when you run into (inexplicable) issues.

Comment: Surely will.
Thanks again.